# How do you throw a grenade?

Tags: lost-planet-2

I started on PC a few days ago and have not found a single hint as to what the grenade button is.

Can someone help?

Comment: just press right click too throw Grenade or T-ENG, You can choose between them with Scroll Down.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>G</kbd> on the keyboard to launch a grenade.

Comment: If you want to share your knowledge, create a new question then answer it yourself. Keep your answers to this question alone.

Comment: @angussidney is right, and for this reason, I have removed that part of your answer. I would recommend seeing if somebody has already asked the question. If not, post it as a new question, and answer it yourself. It's not that we don't want your knowledge, but it must be under an appropriate question in order for other users to find your answer easier. It's not like players trying to find help with it are equally as likely to type in "how do I use the grenade"